# php error on joomla site

Tags: php, joomla, pikachoose

We have two instances running of a joomla hosted site. One is on test server while the other one is on live server.

We are getting one issue where on the test server, site is displaying correctly but not on live server.

We zeroed on one particular line in the page source view, here is the difference of one function from both test as well as live server

test server

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function (){
        $(".pikame403").PikaChoose();
    });

</script>
```

live server

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function (){
        $(".pikame<?=$list['id']?>").PikaChoose();
    });

</script>
```

to me it looks like on the live server, php is not concatinating the id. Any hints/suggestions are welcome.  Also it would be nice if someone could indicate where the addins are store their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all servers allow to use short tags `<?=` for echoing. On your test server short tags switched on, on production -- switched off, so they don't work.

You can solve your problem in 2 ways:

1. Switch on short tags on production server.
2. Do not use short tags (which I strongly recommend). Just change your code `<?=$list['id']?>` to `<?php echo $list['id']; ?>`.

Comment: `<?=` means the same thing as an echo... Perhaps a better suggestion would be to ensure that short tags are enabled.

Comment: It depends on server settings. Not all servers setuped with support of short tags.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it would be better to suggest taking a look at the php configuration before suggesting that the OP changes their usage of short tags. As you can see, in the test server, this option is obviously turned on - that's why it's working.

Comment: @Lix, as for me -- short tags is the reason of many problems, so good idea is to do not use them at all. But I added small explanation.

Comment: @mmochalygin - okay, now that is something that could be useful to others. You have to explain what exactly you are trying to convey as opposed to just saying "change the code like this". Your updated answer is much better now (as you can see by the votes :P ).

Comment: Thanks.. enabled short codes in php.ini and it is working as expected.